# Can you have 2 app.css files or do you have to combine?

Tags: html, css

is it possible to have a website that contains 2 app.css files?

I have a website and want to build a new (but related) website under the same domain.  So I guess you can consider the main hub more like a landing page of sorts, and then the two related "websites" would then branch off of the main domain.  Each of the websites are going to be styled differently though.  So I'm unsure of what is best - to create a single combined app.css file and list each style according to each website, or can I create a new one that sits beside the original?

Comment: Create as many `css` files as you see fit, better yet use `SASS` where you can define css modules, and a main css file which includes relevant/required modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a separate css file for each site, or have them both point to the same file. Since you want different styling between the 2 sites, I'd recommend a different css file for each site.

Comment: Thank you.  I've duplicated the original scss file and changed the styles accordingly.  This was mainly a colour change from the original theme.  Once I have the new scss file, how do I 'point' the new website to use this?  Sorry i know this is pretty basic but I want to be sure I don't mess up my code.  Also, once the scss file is updated, what is the easiest way to get this into the css file?

Answer (score 0):

You **can** create and use as many css file as you want. If both sites will be style differently, create a file (or even multiple files, them import) for each site.

Answer (score 0):

Though the websites are related, it's better to create two separate css files as it will be easy to make changes(in future) to styles and debug incase of any issues. It also increases readability of the code so that in future if you may have to refer this code for any modifications, you can understand it easily and  make required changes :)